# Concurrency of modifying a Roslyn workspace? How does Visual studio do it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

probably a stupid question, but: Is there any way to reliable apply changes to a Roslyn workspace concurrently? And if not, what is the best practice to ensure it's done in correct order?

Example: Say you have some solution loaded into a Workspace, and have a basic function that will add a new project to the solution:

```
private Workspace _workspace;

// This is not thread-safe, right?
void AddProject()
{
  var project = _workspace.CurrentSolution.AddProject(/* ... */);
  _workspace.TryApplyChanges(project.Solution);
}
```

First question: Correct me if wrong, but I think AddProject would not be thread-safe, is that correct?

For example, lets say you want to add to new projects concurrently. So you call AddProject() twice concurrently.

My understanding is there is a race condition, and you might end up with both projects added (if one of the calls completes TryApplyChanges before the other call reaches _workspace.CurrentSolution), or only one of the projects added (if both calls have reached _worksapce.CurrentSolution before either has executed TryApplyChanges).

Second question: If my understanding is correct, then is there any best way to avoid these concurrency issues? I suppose the only real way would be to schedule/execute each modification sequentually, right?

How does Visual Studio, for example, do this.. Are modifications to the Workspace e.g. only done on the Dispatcher?

Thanks

Comment: Lets check implementations of [OnProjectAdd](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Workspace.cs,9ef42d309f40029e). It use `SemaphoreSlim` so yes, it's thread-safe and all of derived workspaces call it as I know.

Comment: Thanks - but I think applying a change will increase the solution's WorkspaceVersion, which could mean that the next update will fail regardless as these won't match anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying code is thread-safe, but your usage is not.

`TryApplyChanges()` will return false if the solution changed in the meantime.  If that happens, you need to try the changes again (starting from the new `CurrentSolution`).

Basically, you need to write

```
Solution changed;
do {
  changed = _workspace.CurrentSolution....();
} while (!_workspace.TryApplyChanges(changed);
```

This is called a compare-and-swap loop; see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures/#compare-and-swap-loops) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good (guess you meant to negate the last condition)! You wouldn't happen to know by any chance if this is a common practice (lets say VS or any other major Roslyn-based software handles it that way)? E.g. wondering if under any circumstances whatsoever TryApplyChanges could always fail for a certain modification, leaving you in an endless loop there

Comment: @Bogey: No; it only returns false if the solution doesn't match.  http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Workspace.cs,1109